# Open source CPU HDL decriprion?

Tags: cpu, hdl

I'd like to get familar with an implemebtaion of modern CPUs. Are there Amy processors with an open-source Hardware Decriprion Language? Perfectlt, I'd like to take a look at Intel/AMD implemebtaion, but Im not sure it is open.

**So is there any CPU with an open source decription? I'm loooking for any architecture: x86, Arm, DEC-Aplha, etc...**

Comment: This is unfortunately one of those cases where you're simply asking people to enter text into a search engine for you.

Comment: There are plenty of CPUs over on opencores.org. RISCV is gaining popularity

Comment: Yes there is. LEON (Sparc) is one.

Comment: I don't think that question should have been closed. It's vague but there are actually valuable answers (about hobby cores vs properly design, clones of legacy CPUs or RISCV, traditional HDLs vs Chisel or Spinal...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very quick search brought up OpenRISC - it is in Verilog.

Comment: Verilog is an HDL.